# Python PermissionError: [Errno13] with fits file

Tags: python, windows, permissions, fits

I've been trying to open this fits file that contains spectra data, but I can't get around this permissionerror. My account is set as the administrator, I have run the program as administrator, and I am on windows. 
This is the code:

```
 from astropy.io import fits
 import os
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import numpy as np 
 os.chdir("C:/Users/jbhis/Documents")
 hdulist = fits.open('spec1d.mctL.245.b21rgb152821.fits.')
```

Comment: Can you open the file directly with the basic `open()` function in Python? If so, this wouldn't have anything to do with Astropy or FITS. What does the exact error message and traceback show?

Comment: I did notice you have a `.` at the end of the filename. Normally that shouldnt cause a permission error per se, but it is highly unusual. Are you sure that's what you intended?